# Разделение строки и обращение к ее первому элементу

Tags: c#, .net

Ребят, подскажите, можно ли в Шарпе разделить строку на несколько частей и допустим обратиться к ее первому элементу? То есть предположим у нас есть строка "Hello world", мы ее разделили на две части с помощью Сплита и теперь я хочу обратиться к первому слову "Hello" и провести над ним какие-либо действия

Comment: split() что возвращает?

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "Hello World";
string[] parts = a.Split();
string second = parts[1];
Console.WriteLine(second[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Hello World";
string[] words = str.Split(' '); //делим по пробелу
string hello = words[0];
Console.WriteLine(hello); //вывести в консоль "Hello"
Console.WriteLine(hello.Length); //вывести в консоль число символов в слове "Hello"
hello = hello.Replace('e', 'a'); //заменить все символы 'e' на символы 'a' в строке
Console.WriteLine(hello); //вывести в консоль "Hallo"
```

IDE по Ctrl+Space может много чего предложить, нужно учитывать что текущая строка НЕ может быть изменена, а в качестве ответа возвращается новая (или другие типы ответа, массив строк, массив символов, числа, true/false, итд...), которую можно подставить вместо прежней.